# How to pass url´s to puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I need to let puppeteer with head keep running and pass url´s to it to be shown in browser. Url will be passed from mqtt subscription. Trying to create some kind of url slideshow. so… where to begin?

I´m tried soeme example but have not been able to pass new url´s to a already running browser window

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var pt = require('puppeteer');
var Topic = 'url'; //subscribe to all topics
var Broker_URL = 'mqtt://192.168.2.3';
var endpoint;
var browser2;

var options = {
    clientId: 'MyMQTT',
    port: 1883,
    keepalive: 60
};

var client = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL, options);
client.on('connect', mqtt_connect);
client.on('reconnect', mqtt_reconnect);
client.on('error', mqtt_error);
client.on('message', mqtt_messsageReceived);
client.on('close', mqtt_close);

launchbrowser();

async function launchbrowser() {
    const browser = await pt.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://tools4testing.com/');
    endpoint = browser.wsEndpoint();
    await browser.disconnect();
    
}



function mqtt_connect() {
    console.log("Connecting MQTT");
    client.subscribe(Topic, mqtt_subscribe);
}

function mqtt_subscribe(err, granted) {
    console.log("Subscribed to " + Topic);
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
}

function mqtt_reconnect(err) {
    console.log("Reconnect MQTT");
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    client = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL, options);
}

function mqtt_error(err) {
    console.log("Error!");
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
}

function after_publish() {
    //do nothing
}

function mqtt_messsageReceived(topic, message, packet) {
    
    console.log('Topic=' + topic + '  Message=' + message);
    console.log(endpoint);
      await pt.connect({browserWSEndpoint: endpoint},);
    
}

function mqtt_close() {
    console.log("Close MQTT");
}
```

Comment: `page.goto(url)`?

Comment: that is what Iˋve testet. But how to keep the browser running and pass a new url whenever I get a new value from the mqtt server?

Comment: `page.goto(url)` is how to do it. What do you mean by "pass a new url?"

Comment: i need to keep the browser running an open a new url every time new data arrives from mqtt broker. data from mqtt contain a new url to be opened in current page on browser

Comment: That's exactly what `page.goto(url)` does. Did you try my suggestion? It's the equivalent of typing a URL into the navigation bar and pressing Enter as a normal user visiting a website.

Comment: I attached my code to the question. (Code from google).

Initial page load is working. In the function mqtt_messsageReceived I wan't to reconnect to my browser and open a new page from the content from mqtt. I do not understand how to do this... :-)

Comment: Well, `await pt.connect({browserWSEndpoint: endpoint},);` resolves to the `browser` object, and from a `browser`, you can create a `page`, and with the `page` you can `goto()`. You've already performed these steps in `launchbrowser` so it's the same code, basically.